# How do I keep the header (column names) visible while scrolling in an SSRS report USING SQL SERVER REPORT BUILDER 2014?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have looked at many questions that have already been answered but none of them have helped me solve my problem. I believe its because most of them were using SQL Server 2008. I am using SQL Server Report Builder 2014 and would like to have my column names displayed while scrolling down a report. There are many columns in my report so this would be extremely helpful. I have tried setting FixedData equal to true under the static element for tablix properties but this does not change anything. When I go to my report the column names disappear (stay at the top) when I scroll down the page. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 2014 installed right now Tommy, but I can confirm with RB 2016 that the tablix "Keep header visible while scrolling" still **doesn't** work but that the advanced property of "FixedData" **does** work.  This is the behavior that I've experienced from 2008R2 all the way to 2016 so I would be surprised if 2014 was any different.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help! If figured out the issue what not with report builder, rather with the application I am displaying the reports with